# Lamp visible in solid shading, but not in rendered mode

Tags: rendering, lighting

[image]so I'm new to blender. I was following this tutorial and found out I might have done something wrong. In object mode -> solid, I can see my lamp and the effect it has. In object mode -> rendered it's just dark and no sign of a lamp nor light.The strenght of the lamp is high enough.

Can someone help me out and tell me what I might have done wrong?

Comment: Add a screenshot to your question

Comment: @Crantisz done :)

Comment: @Lisa first, that one on the right is not "solid mode" but "rendered mode", then, you wrote two times "solid mode"  above...  then , why did you set "background" as surface, instead of "emission"?

Comment: @m.ardito oh crap, sorry! I meant render mode!
I have no idea why, but this just solved my problem. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

**Strength** 18 for cycles spot lamp is to low. Try to increase this value up to 1000 or more

[image]
[image]

Comment: This didn't work, I don't even have that faint light/light grey area like in the top picture..

Comment: This setup is pointing in the right direction, but probably @Lisa just mistakenly set a wrong "surface" type.

Comment: @m.ardito this was the problem indeed, thank you!